# UITextfield text clipping issue in Storyboard - iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, xcode-storyboard

I am trying to design some reusable table cell for my tableview.

however when i adjust the text to make it center vertical of my UITextField, the text always clipped at the bottom.

Is this a storyboard display issue? Or some configuration i miss out?

Any advice?

[Figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhhTL.png)

Comment: I face the same issue, but at runtime it gets fine, I think this may be cause of storyboard.

Comment: Try tu run the project. It's just the Xcode bug in storyboard's displaying

Comment: Thanks guys, seems like it is a display issue of storyboard. runtime is fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not an issue with your designing. Run the project, it will show it perfectly.

Designer:

[image]

When running:

[image]